Change route color in terminal
Does anyone know how I can have that colored background in my routes, in the github branch and the icons. I currently use the Hyper terminal with the dracula theme
Terminal currently:

For example:


If you want to do have that customization in any shell, you can use oh-my-posh. Otherwise, you can use Zsh with oh-my-zsh to manage your configuration files.
